# Fourier Transform of $\frac{1}{1+|x|^\alpha}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to figure out either of these two things:
$\int_w \frac{e^{iwt}}{1+|w|^\alpha}$ or $\sum_{n \in Z} \frac{e^{int}}{1+|n|^\alpha}$, for $0<\alpha<1$

I think I know roughly what the asymptotics would look like for small t (UV): one can do a inverse fourier transform of $|w|^{-\alpha}$ and the answer would look like $\propto |t|^{\alpha-1}$.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!